# Is the time complexity of this code correct?

Tags: c, time-complexity

Calculate the time complexity of this code fragment if  the function "process" has a complexity of O(logn)

```
void funct (int a[], int n)
{
    int i=0
      while (i < n){
         process (a, n);
         if (a[i]%2 == 0)
           i = i*2+1;
         else
           i = i+1;
  }
```

I tried to calculate the best and worst case for time complexity;

Worst case is when the "else" statement get called so it should just be:

Worst case : T(n) = O(nlogn)

I have some problems with the best case. I tried this way but i don't know if this is correct

Since in the "if" statement "i" get incremented by "2i+1" it should be

```
i=2^k-1
2^k < n+1 

so k < log_2(n+1)
```

Is correct to say that the while loop get executed `(log_2(n+1)-2)/2` times because this is the last possible value for which i < n ?

if so the time complexity is O(lognlogn) in best case?

Comment: Complexities are correct but the while loop is executed `ceil(log_2(n+1))` times. 
After first iteration `i = 1`. After second `i = 2+1`. After third `i = 2^2+2+1` and so on. After last i.e `kth` iteration `i = 2^k-1 >= n`. So `k` must be `ceil(log_2(n+1))`. Please correct me if you find this wrong.

Comment: Yes you are right thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best case is if the sampled values in `a` are all even.  In that case, the complexity is `O(log(n)*log(n))`, since the loop trip count is `O(log(n))`.

The worst case is if the sampled values in `a` are all odd.  In that case, the complexity is `O(n*log(n))`, since the loop trip count is `O(n)`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.(i don't even have the reputation to downvote btw). Could you please  confirm me if in the best case the while loop get executed    (log_2(n+1)-2)/2    times?

Comment: In the best case, the loop trip count is `O(log(n))` since `i` is more than doubled each time and less than tripled, which is all you need to get `O(log(n))`.  I'm not sure if your trip count expression is exact or not in this case, but it's `O(log(n))` which is the important thing.

Comment: Ok thank you very much at least i know the complexity was right :D